# Computer keeps restarting by itself

Tags: crash, reboot

my computer  keeps restarting within 2 seconds, I don't have the time to acess the BIOS or anything. I have to turn off with the switch, and I have to wait like 2 min before trying to restart it if not, it simply won't start.

The 1st restart goes up to the windows logo, but then the computer crashes and keeps crashing after every 2 seconds.

Do you have an idea of what could be the problem? PSU is brand new coolmaster 700W. It's not a super powerfull gaming computer. It's a basic gaming computer.

I'll inspect the parts later this week.

Comment: Do the cooling fans turn? is it full of dust?

Comment: Sounds like a temperature problem. Switch the computer on, go into your BIOS temperature monitoring tab (if present) and wait. Does it still crash when in the BIOS screen? Can you see what the temperature of the CPU is when it crashes?

Comment: I agree that this seems a overheating problem. However you **can** test other things too. E.g. unplugging the HDD (both power and data cable)/ Or removing a graphical card (if it is not build-in). Both should allow your computer to POST. (Not that it will boot without HDD, but it should not shut itself down again.)

Comment: The computer is overheating, if you continue to use it, you will cause damage to the computer itself.  You need to figure out the reason your CPU is overheating.

Comment: Ok, checking bios for temp was already mentioned. Is it better when your case is left open?

Comment: no change when case is open, Now the computer won't even start, I'm afraid I fiend the CPU. I'll buy some thermal paste later today and try what have been mentionned above.

Comment: Just a guess, but I think it's broken.  Maybe you need to take it to someone who knows how to fix broken computers.

Comment: I don't want to pay for food, or rent, but sometimes you gotta pay to play.

Comment: You have asked the same question two other times. 8/11 and 8/24 and now 8/31. Did you perform any of the suggestions?

Comment: I checked the fans, and looked for any poped capacitors, but I did not have the time to check the CPU temps. I was attempting to format the computer. and now, it crashed and its too late, it wont even start. please help

Comment: I suspect that, with all your dinking around, you've damaged several other components.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a problem like this where the CPU fan had stopped. The restart in my case was the safety restart to prevent the CPU from taking damage due to the temperature.

Answer (score 2):

Your computer is definitely overheating.  If it is a tower, it will be much easier to fix.  The same principles apply for a notebook, but it is harder to get to everything, and usually require removing the motherboard.  Obviously power down the computer before attempting anything below.

If you open the side of the tower you will see a 80mm fan on your motherboard.  There should be a (usually silver) block of metal underneath it.  This is your CPU fan and heatsink.  All of the hold downs are different depending on what socket you have, but not matter what, you need to remove them both.  You can remove them as one unit.

Underneath that is your CPU.  You do not need to remove it, but you do need to clean the "goop" off of it with a lint-free cloth and some rubbing alcohol.  That "goop" is called thermal paste, and is available at any local computer store or usually RadioShack.  That will need to be reapplied.  You just want to squeeze a pea-sized amount on top of the middle of your CPU before you put your heatsink and fan back on.

While you have your heatsink and fan removed, take it outside and blow it out with an air compressor or canned air.  Remove as much dust as you can.  Make sure your fan spins freely.  If it doesn't, it will need to be replaced.  Again - a local computer repair store or RadioShack.  Usually it is only a couple of plastic tabs or four screws that hold the fan to the heatsink.

Once you have done all that, put the heatsink and fan back on the CPU, tighten down the hold downs, plug the fan back in, and you should be set to go!

Answer (score 1):

I think the first answer is on the money but, if a check of the the cpu fan shows it is working, then I would remove it and check the thermal paste. Sometimes this paste will dry out and leave the CPU thermally disconnected from the heat sink, basically trapping the heat on the CPU.

If you have a power source independent of the computer, I would check the fan operation with that. If the fan runs like it should, then I would clean the old paste off of the CPU, apply the new paste and reassemble. If the fan stops running, then I would replace the fan and thermal paste, CPU fans do go bad sometimes.