# Computer crashes every 2 to 10 minutes

Tags: crash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer keeps restarting by itself](https://superuser.com/questions/460525/computer-keeps-restarting-by-itself)

My computer turns off every 2 or 10 minutes. I formatted it and the samething happens. After it shuts down, I cannot restart it right away, I have to turn off the power switch then wait a couple of minutes to turn it back on(and it does not always turn on, I have to have more time sometimes). Please help me, this is very frustrating, I dont what is the problem, It seems to me that it is either the power supply or the hard drive, but the power supply is 6 months old.

Thank you