# Computer is totally crashed

Tags: crash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer keeps restarting by itself](https://superuser.com/questions/460525/computer-keeps-restarting-by-itself)

my computer kept restarting on its own at random times varying from 1 minutes, to 20 minutes(then goind in a constant restart loop every ~10 seconds). I had to turn it off and wait minutes or hours before attempting to restarting to go further in the boot process.
Now, it just does not turn on.

I posted this before: 
[Computer crashes every 2 to 10 minutes](https://superuser.com/q/465887/146341)

but I did not have the time to check the temperature.

I don't want to pay to get it checked up, but I want to know what is wrong. Is the processor fried?

Thank you